# java ternary operator internals + intellij evaluate expression

Tags: java, intellij-idea, ternary-operator, jls

This code will throw NPE:

```
Integer wtf = false ? 1 : (Integer) null;
```

thing is, if either 2nd or 3rd operand is int, then the other one will also be converted to int. (according to tables in this part of JLS https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.25)

My first question is, why is specification written in this way? Doesn't it make more sense, to convert value to more expressive option (Integer), than to more primitive one (int)? To prevent this kind of extremely confusing bugs?

Second question is, you can successfully evaluate that expression in Intellij's evaluate expression. Result will be wtf object with assigned null. Is it bug, or is somewhere specified that it is not JLS compliant?

Comment: "Second question... Is it bug" Yes, that would be a bug in intellij.

Comment: FYI: Google's Error Prone [has a check for this](http://errorprone.info/bugpattern/NullTernary).

Comment: If intellj is setting it null, then it is definitely a bug as eclipse is correctly throwing null pointer exception. Why is JLS like this? Only those who have written this can answer. Maybe for better performance.

Comment: It's a pity the JLS authors didn't publish a rationale document the same way the ISO standards committee [did for the C language](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/C99RationaleV5.10.pdf).

Comment: For the second question, let me turn it upside-down: is it anywhere specified that IntelliJ "evaluate expression" *is* JLS-compliant? Or is it just assumed?

Comment: @DodgyCodeException I think that expecting debbuger of one of the most used IDE to be JLS compliant is not very bold assumption. 

But that rationale for C is very nice.

Answer (score 1):

> why is specification written in this way?

I can't answer *why*, because I didn't write the spec. But I can suggest a reason why it *shouldn't* be otherwise.

When the second and third parameters are of differing types, and both types are convertible to numeric types, they undergo [*binary numeric promotion*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se9/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.6.2). This is the same as with other operators taking numeric operands, e.g. `+`.

You can get the same NPE if you try to add an `int` and an `Integer null`:

```
System.out.println(1 + (Integer) null);
```

In this case you can't do anything useful by boxing the 1 to `Integer.valueOf(1)`.

It would be inconsistent if numeric types were handled differently between the `+` and `?:` operators (*). And the conditional operator needs to employ *some form* of binary numeric promotion in order to be able to handle primitive operands of differing types, e.g. `int` and `double`.

A glance at the [specification for the conditional operator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se9/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.25) should convince you that its type handling is already *insanely* complicated (see tables 15.25-A through E), and so it shouldn't be made more so.

It's unfortunate that you're able to shoot yourself in the foot this way; but that's just how the language is.

I consider the problem here to be with auto-boxing as a general language feature; without that, there would be no such problem, because you would have to do the unboxing yourself.

---

(*) Actually, it does behave a little differently. For example, `(Integer) null + (Integer) null` would be auto-unboxed, whereas `condition ? (Integer) null : (Integer) null` would *not* be auto-unboxed. This difference arises because the conditional operator specifies that there is a check for same operand types prior to the binary numeric promotion being applied.

Comment: I would say, that it wouldn't be any more complicated, to use wrapper class when dealing with primitive+it's wrapper combination in ?: operator. And BNP isn't used in this case even now.. 

but ok, but this might be one of those things, where are arguments for both sides and neither is significantly better.

Answer (score 0):

- I guess the reasons were efficiency and simplicity: **less memory and direct access** instead of via the *Integer* wrapper object. Otherwise, e. g.  in `Integer wtf = 40 + (false ? Integer.valueOf("1") : 2));` an *Integer* instance would have to be generated as an intermediate result.
  The tables you are referring to became necessary by **boxing/unboxing** with Java 5. In Java 1.4 it was not allowed to use both an *int* and an *Integer* for the second and third operands.
- Yes, that is a bug because it is violating the JLS.